# Google sheets query Order by

Tags: google-sheets, sql-order-by

I have a query that selects * from column A, column B, column C.

Column A is dates. B is income. C is debts.

How do I order by A, B so B entries return before C entries when they have the same date?

```
Jan1 income
Jan1 income
jan1           debts
Jan2 income
Jan2           debts
Jan2           debts
Etc
```

Sorry I'm on my phone so was going to add a screenshot that would clarify much easier but it is saying the image is to large lol ..um this is a site about coding and they can't run a simple optimization script?

Comment: Post few of your sample data. You current example showing income and debt in same column. I assume it will be in two separate column.

Comment: Sry  Yes 2 columns...I have edited my question. They way I am working around it is by putting income on its own sheet and querying Income!A:A debts A:A...

Answer (score 0):

You can `union all` two queries, one from B and one from C, and add a fictitious column just for the ordering:

```sql
SELECT   a, b
FROM     (SELECT a, b, 1 AS ordering_col
          FROM   mytable
          ORDER BY
          SELECT a, c, 2 AS ordering_col
          FROM   mytable) t
ORDER BY a ASC, ordering_col ASC
```

Comment: Google-sheet will not support it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Order by Col1,Col2 DESC